# Execute default event before custom click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to execute the default event of a button before executing my custom function

my code:

```
$('#Button').click( function (){
    sideMenuCheck();
});
```

I wan't this to be executed after the default event of the function
Like this:

```
$('#Button').click( function (){
    **event.default();**
    sideMenuCheck();
});
```

but I didn't find any solution.

---

**Not important**

I'm doing this because I have an off-canvas menu, and menu has to be with the visible height after it opens, (#Button) is the button that opens menu from the side.

Comment: I guess you should instead ask question regarding your former issue, not the workaround you think would fix it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wrap up your code in a `setTimeout` with a timeout of `0` - this will cause it to move your code to the bottom of the execution queue, and allow everything else to run first:

```
$('#Button').click( function (){
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        sideMenuCheck();
    }, 0);
});
```