# Bind devextreme text value to angular model (on keydown)

Tags: devextreme

I'm just starting out trialling DevExtreme HTML components. Currently, I'm trying to get a simple search form working with AngularJS and DevExtreme.

I want to submit the search form by pressing enter. The problem is the widget seems to only update the angular model if I tab out of the field (presumably onValueChanged event).

In the following code I observe the value of `searchData.q` changes only when tabbing out of the field. So when the form is submitted in the `onKeyChange` event, it's using the previous text value. It seems a bit counterintuitive for text boxes to act this way, definitely base angular doesn't work like this with ng-model...

Does anyone know how to fix it so the value is properly bound?

```
<form id="HeaderSearchForm" ng-submit="search">
   <div dx-form="searchFormOptions"></div>
</form>
<pre>
{{searchData | json}}
</pre>
```

In the angular controller:

```
app.controller('HeaderCtrl', ['$scope', 'authorityService', function ($scope, authorityService) {
  var execSearch, searchData = {}, searchFormOptions;

  $scope.searchFormOptions = {
    formData: searchData,
    items: [{
      dataField: 'q',
      label: {
        text: 'Search'
      },
      bindingOptions: {
        "formData.q": "searchData.q"
      },

      editorOptions: {
        mode: 'search',
        placeholder: 'Enter a search query',
        onKeyDown: function(e){
          var keyCode = e.jQueryEvent.which;
          if (keyCode === 13){
            search();
          }
        }
      }
    }]
  };

  search = function(){
    alert('searching for ' + searchData.q);
  };

  $scope.searchData = searchData;
  $scope.search = search;

}]);
```

Comment: Found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842378/execute-default-event-before-custom-click-function - tried wrapping the search function in a timeout, it works, value is updated before the function call, but seems a bit hacky. Perhaps a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [valueChangeEvent](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxTextBox/Configuration/#valueChangeEvent) option is helpful in your case. Change it to `keydown`:

```
editorOptions: {
    mode: 'search',
    placeholder: 'Enter a search query',
    onKeyDown: function(e) {
        //...
    },
    valueChangeEvent: "keydown"
}
```

See this [sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/DcE6kC86VhdwIuI5W77c?p=preview) as well.

Comment: oh I see, it's set as an option. It's seems like a very nice framework so far. Thanks Sergey much appreciated.